# Fail to install firebase module on node js: error 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

I want to use firebase inside my react app.
I'm new to react so i used this tutorial to create my react app:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

I have:
Node js version: v8.9.4
npm version: 5.6.0

im running:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

and getting:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @firebase/app@0.1.10

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\...\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-10T10_44_12_593Z-debug.log
```

this is my package json:

```
{
"name": "profile-editor",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
"react-editable-json-tree": "^2.2.0",
"react-firebase": "^2.2.8",
"react-json-edit": "^0.3.1",
"react-scripts": "1.1.1",
"update-notifier": "^2.4.0"
  },
"scripts": {
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I checked with a friend and he can download this module(with an older node js version). I tried this command from my home net and my phone's hotspot in case its a network issue. same error. This is very strange! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried

```
npm install firebase --save
```

again(thanks to Dhana), 3 month later, without even updating node(which i'm quite sure i tried back then), and it worked. still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue , I have updated my node js using

```
    npm update node
```

and then tried

```
  npm install firebase --save
```

Below is the image of error I have faced and the fix.

Thank you[image]